# How to access data outside of an if statement in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I want to use the variables or array outside of the if statement. In javascript, you can hoist the variables outside of the if statement, but not sure how to do it in swift? I have tried using a struct, but I am not sure which direction to go in. I want to use `num` in a function and increment through each array. But, need to be able to access variables through the file.

```
let jsonWithArrayRoot = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: fileData, options: [])

var zone: Int
var sound: String
var distance: Int
var title: String
var duration: Int
var type: String
var color: Int
var num:Int

num=0

if let array = jsonWithArrayRoot as? [AnyObject] {
    let json = array[num]

    test = array

    zone = json["zone"] as? Int ?? 0
    sound = json["sound"] as? String ?? ""
    distance = json["distance"] as? Int ?? 0
    title = json["title"] as? String ?? ""
    duration = json["duration"] as? Int ?? 0
    type = json["type"] as? String ?? ""
    color = json["color"] as? Int ?? 0

    print(zone)

}


//I want to access variables and later on    
print(zone)
print(sound)
print(distance)
print(title)
print(type)
print(color)
```

Comment: Swift is complaining because the value of those variables is *undefined* if the `if` branch is never entered - you need to provide a default or initial value for those variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use guard.

guard let array = jsonWithArrayRoot as? [AnyObject] else { return }

let json = array[num]

```
zone = json["zone"] as? Int ?? zone
sound = json["sound"] as? String ?? sound
distance = json["distance"] as? Int ?? distance
title = json["title"] as? String ?? title
duration = json["duration"] as? Int ?? duration
type = json["type"] as? String ?? type
color = json["color"] as? Int ?? color
```

Use array variable anywhere now.

Comment: it is giving me an error of return invalid outside of a func

Comment: Yes return can be used inside a function. I misinterpreted your question. You wanted to use your other variables.

Comment: I always declare my variables as. var zone: Int? = 0

Comment: How would you return the array using this? It works inside the function, can I return the object?

func someFunc() -> AnyObject{
    

    guard let array = jsonWithArrayRoot as? [AnyObject] else { return }
    
 
    return array;

}

Comment: And always use if let -or- guard let to avoid crash.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: @MichaelZaladonis Yes, you can return anything using guard. Your someFunc() looks good.

Answer (score 1):

You should give your variables default values right away, and then change them later based on the JSON data. Your current code puts the default values *inside* the JSON parsing block, which means that the variables would have no value if the `if let array = jsonWithArrayRoot...` fails.

Personally, I would also refactor the `as? Int ??` lines to something prettier, but that's another issue.

Here's your code with a minimal fix that should work nicely:

```
let jsonWithArrayRoot = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: fileData, options: [])

var zone = 0
var sound = ""
var distance = 0
var title = ""
var duration = 0
var type = ""
var color = 0
var num = 0

if let array = jsonWithArrayRoot as? [AnyObject] {
    let json = array[num]

    zone = json["zone"] as? Int ?? zone
    sound = json["sound"] as? String ?? sound
    distance = json["distance"] as? Int ?? distance
    title = json["title"] as? String ?? title
    duration = json["duration"] as? Int ?? duration
    type = json["type"] as? String ?? type
    color = json["color"] as? Int ?? color
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. How would refactor the 'as? Int ??' ?